# ASUS Laptop Wifi Driver

Tags: drivers

I recently did a clean install of windows 7 on my Asus x550ca laptop. I was able to downlaod the ethernet driver, but I want the wifi driver. On the driver page for my model, there is four different Wireless drvers and I do not know which one to install. And would I have to install a bluetooth driver as well?

Link to driver page: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=X550CA&p=3&s=516

Answer (score 1):

If you're not sure, use trial and error. Install one of them one at a time, if the driver doesn't work uninstall it and try to install the the other. It's up to you if you want to have bluetooth connection, you need to install driver for it too.